# Need an approach for this

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms, maxima-minima, functional-inequalities

What is the range of the function
$\frac{\log{x}}{x}$.

I want an approach to this problem and not just an answer.

How do I approach such problems?

Comment: You can kinda only speak of a function, when you have a domain and codomain given. But $\log(x)\leq x-1$, then $\frac{\log(x)}{x}\leq\frac{x-1}{x}=1-\frac{1}{x}$. Therefore the range has to be upperbounded by 1.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\right)'=\frac{1-\ln{x}}{x^2},$$
which says that $x_{max}=e$ and $\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\leq\frac{1}{e}$.

By the way, the domain is $(0,+\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\ln{x}}{x}=-\infty$.

Since our function is a continuous function, we get the answer: $\left(-\infty,\frac{1}{e}\right]$.

Comment: what after that.....I need more help sir

Comment: @Yash Vaibhav I added something. See now please.